# Return None when attribute does not exist

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, oop, attributes

```
class test(object):
def __init__(self, a = 0):
    test.a = a

t = test()

print test.a ## obviously we get 0

''' ====== Question ====== '''

print test.somethingelse ## I want if attributes not exist, return None. How to do that?
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__ , although I wonder why you want to do this. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First of all, you are adding the variable to the class `test.a = a`. You should be adding it to the instance, `self.a = a`. Because, when you add a value to the class, all the instances will share the data.

You can use [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?object.__getattr__#object.__getattr__) function like this

```
    class test(object):
        def __init__(self, a = 0):
            self.a = a

        def __getattr__(self, item):
            return None

    t = test()

    print t.a
    print t.somethingelse
```

Quoting from the `__getattr__` docs,

> **Called when an attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the usual places** (i.e. it is not an instance attribute nor is it found in the class tree for self). name is the attribute name.

**Note:** The advantage of `__getattr__` over [`__getattribute__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) is that, `__getattribute__` will be called always, we have to handle manually even if the current object has the attribute. But, `__getattr__` will *not* be called if the attribute is found in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [`__getattribute__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) hook.  Something like this should do what you want:

```
class test(object):
    def __init__(self, a = 0):
        self.a = a

    def __getattribute__(self, attr):
        try:
            return object.__getattribute__(self, attr)
        except AttributeError:
            return None
```

Comment: Do you mean `__getattr__`?

Comment: @FelixKling No. See the manual section I linked to.  (It is my understanding that both work, but `__getattribute__` is preferred for new code.)

Comment: `__getattribute__` might be inefficient, as the control reaches it always, even if the the item being searched is in the hierarchy.

Comment: The link just brings me to the top of the page. That's why I first thought you meant the other method. More useful link: http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?#object.__getattribute__

Comment: @FelixKling Link should be fixed now.